# An easy riddle at its core

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

You are what you eat, so I suspect you like sweets, for I think that’s what you are.

A plain figure you have, with rounded sides, a symbol quite bizarre.

I hear the mad hatter gave up tea for you, and you’re hiding in plain sight.

You may be arrested if you push too hard, or are taken affright.

But I would move the earth for you, or then again, maybe not.

Who are you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd love the answer to be a

> heart

You are what you eat, so I suspect you like sweets, for I think that’s what you are.

> you think they are a sweetheart (also a candy), and heart contains 'are' rearranged

A plain figure you have, with rounded sides, a symbol quite bizarre.

> the $\large\color{red}♥$ symbol, (a stretch produced by keypad Alt + 3 is alternative odd) - I'm missing a clue here

I hear the mad hatter gave up tea for you, and you’re hiding in plain sight.

> anagram hatter - t = heart, and hiding in: I *hear t*he

You may be arrested if you push too hard, or are taken afright.

> pushing too hard or a fright may cause a cardiac arrest

But I would move the earth for you, or then again, maybe not.

> anagram earth to heart, but you don't want the anagram to be hater

Title: An easy riddle at its core

> the core is the heart of this matter

Comment: Correct solution; some different interpretations in the workings to my original intentions (i.e. 1st line, and computer reference in second line, and "missing second half").

Comment: I tried a little rearrangement, but am still missing some better explanations!

Comment: To be honest, I think your workings are better than my originals!  I'll share mine now that this is solved, just so you can see my original thoughts...

Comment: Wow this is clever! :) I thought the answer was going to be ‘apple’, except for the part about the Mad Hatter.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are

> the moon

"You are what you eat, so I suspect you like sweets, for I think that’s what you are."

> A moon pie is a type of sweet

"A plain figure you have, with rounded sides, a symbol quite bizarre."

> Mooncakes are flat and round, usually with a design on the top featuring Chinese characters or elements of nature

"I hear the mad hatter gave up tea for you, and you’re hiding in plain sight."

> The moon is a symbol of lunacy

"You may be arrested if you push too hard, or are taken affright."

> Mooning (pushing out your bare bum) could get you arrested (thanks @Phylyp!)

"But I would move the earth for you, or then again, maybe not."

> The moon moves the tides, but not the earth itself

Comment: Nice interpretation! For being arrested, I wonder if [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mooning) might be it?

Comment: Very nice answer.  Sadly not quite what I was shooting for, but clever interpretation.

Comment: Given your profile, I reckon you can decode this to get the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since Tom's already solved the quiz with his [excellent answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66668/1681), I'm sharing my workings here.  Some of his reasoning was better than in my original, but sharing mine for all to consider / critique:

> "You are what you eat, so I suspect you like sweets, for I think that’s what you are."
>
> > You are a sweet; or rather a suit; i.e. Hearts is a suit of cards in the standard deck (♥|♠|♦|♣).
>
> "A plain figure you have, with rounded sides, a symbol quite bizarre."
>
> > The heart symbol (❤) is a plain figure (2D shape) with rounded sides.  The symbol's quite bizarre given what it represents looks pretty different.
> >  [image: Image from http://mentalfloss.com/article/29989/why-dont-valentine-hearts-look-real-hearts]
>
> I hear the mad hatter gave up tea for you
>
> > mad = anagram (e.g. mixed up).  
> >  hatter gave up tea = HATTER - T = HATER.  
> >  HEART is an anagram of HATER.
>
> and you’re hiding in plain sight.
>
> > Refers back to the start of the sentence, where HEART appears in plain sight:  
> >  I **HEAR T**he mad hatter gave up tea for you
>
> You may be arrested if you push too hard, or are taken affright.
>
> > If overworked, or a sudden fright causes the heart to race, it may bring on cardiac arrest.
>
> But I would move the earth for you
>
> > If you move the letters in EARTH again you get HEART.
>
> or then again, maybe not.
>
> > I had a change of heart
>
> Who are you?
>
> > A heart
>
> Title: An easy riddle at its core
>
> > The word "core" is a synonym for heart
>
> Clue: On [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66664/1681) I commented: "Very nice answer. Sadly not quite what I was *shooting* for, but clever interpretation."
>
> > That answer suggested `the moon`  
> >  [Shooting the moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts#Shooting_the_moon) is a term from the card game Hearts.
>
> Clue: On [that same answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66664/1681) I also commented: "Given your profile, I reckon you can decode this to get the right answer".
>
> > The user's username is `codehearts`  
> >  If you de-code (remove code from) codehearts you're left with hearts

Comment: ps. it was just pointed out that I'd been mispronouncing Suit as Suite/Sweet, so my version of that first clue doesn't work!  So even bigger congratulations to Tom for finding a version that made sense!